# UiScrollView Incorrect Height (Without AutoConstraint)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uilabel

Searched a lot on stack overflow, but didn't find any solution that works for us.

What we have are a couple of Views and `UILabels` and `UIButtons` in `UIScrollView` as below format. On Click of button we are hiding couple of views and labels and trying to recalculate `UIScollView` height.

```
UIScrollView
```

**-->UIView**

**-->UIView2**

**-->UIView3**

**-->UILabel1**

**-->UILabel2** ( Please note these labels are not inside `UIView`, they are directly added to `scrollview`. Is this correct approach or they should be added inside a `UIView`?)

**-->UITextField (Directly added to scrollview)**

**-->UITextField1 (Directly added to scrollview)**

**-->UIButton** ( On Click of Button above `textfields` and labels are hidden or shown based on business logic)

When we try to reset size of `UIScrollview` on `UIButton` click it doesn't calculate height correctly. Tried below solution shared by lot of answers in stack overflow

1. Is the problem with labels and buttons added directly to `UIScrollView`?
2. Is there better way to set height of `UIScrollview` correctly?
3. We don't want to use `AutoConstraint`

   ```
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;for (UIView *view in uiScrollViewObj.subviews) {
       contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
   }
   uiScrollViewObj.contentSize = contentRect.size;
   ```

Comment: are you trying to change the height of the inner content, or the height of the scrollview itself?

Comment: Change height of uiScrollView

Comment: uiScrollViewObj.contentSize changes the size of the inner area where you can scroll, and doesn't change the scrollview's height, you have to change the scrollview's frame.

Comment: let me try that. Is there example you can share

Comment: Here is what i tried after getting content size .. didn't worked. Now i cannot even scroll uiScollviewObj.frame = CGRectMake(10,  20, viewWidth, contentRect.size.height);

Comment: i suggest you rewrite your question more clear, (edit it) and use images.

Answer (score 0):

1. No it's not, in fact UILabels and UIButtons are UIViews.
2. I think you are confusing two concepts. The UIScrollView height is the height of the viewport (the visible part of the scrollview). What you want to change is the contentSize height that is the height of the whole content which you want to scroll through (I don't know if I have explain myself clear).

If the structure is the way you said it, so the UIButton is the closest element to the button, you should move its frame and place it upper, otherwise the contentSize is always gonna be the same.

Besides that, your code is iterating through all the views of the scrollview and those are not only the ones you added but also the ones that Apple inserted.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought of doing it manually but thought there might be easy way to achieve this which i missed. I'll give it a try

Comment: So issue was fixed by manually looping through all child View elements and setting contentSize. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

The best way to calculate the contentsize dynamically is to sum scrollview subviews y position and their height. Something like this should work:

```
CGFloat viewY, maxY=0;
for (UIView *view in uiScrollViewObj.subviews) {
    if (view.hidden) continue;
    viewY = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height;
    maxY = (viewY > maxY) ? viewY : maxY;
}
[uiScrollViewObj setContentSize:CGSizeMake(uiScrollViewObj.frame.size.width, maxY)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried above code it doesn't decrease height if we hide a view. There is additional scroll below

Comment: Edited above code to not include the view if hidden. The additional scroll should not appear now.

Comment: So issue was fixed by manually looping through all child View elements and setting contentSize. Thanks for your reply. I'm puzzled why solution given by you didn't worked. It makes sense. Is there bug in uiScollView?

Comment: Well, this is exactly what above code is doing, looping through childviews and setting contentSize. Anyway, glad you found your solution! :)